# How to get underlying code from a .dyn file

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, revit

I am trying to get the code from a dynamo file so that I can use it in a C# plugin for Revit. When I open the .dyn file all I see is a bunch of xml. I tried parsing it but this does not help. I am looking for a more automatic way than rewriting all the different methods in visual studio. Is there a way to extract the dynamo script code so that can be run from a plugin? I read that dynamo runs on the .NET framework so I am guessing it must be compiled into this type of code at some point? Any help is much appreciated